# Why does the conditional independent rule of INTERSECTION require STRICT POSITIVE DISTRIBUTION?

Tags: probability-theory, graph-theory, conditional-probability, independence, bayesian-network

Recently, I was confused with the proofs of some conditional independent rules (decomposition, weak union, contraction, intersection), particularly the conditional independent rule of **INTERSECTION**.

In the book *Probabilistic Graphical Models Principles and Techniques*, Page25 mentioned that the **STRICT POSITIVE DISTRIBUTION** is necessary for **INTERSECTION** rule.

**INTERSECTION** rule states:

*For positive distributions, and for mutually disjoint sets X, Y, Z, W: (X⊥Y|Z,W)&(X⊥W|Z,Y) ⇒ (X⊥Y,W|Z). (2.11)*

But according to definition (2.3) in the same book on Page24, the right side of (2.11) is trivially established for some events {y1, w1, z1} which leads P(Y=y1, W=w1, Z=z1)=0, it seems **STRICT POSITIVE DISTRIBUTION** is not necessary for **INTERSECTION** rule.

Definition (2.3) states:

*We say that an event a is conditionally independent of event b given event r in P, denoted P ⊨ (a⊥b|r), if P(a|b ∩ r) = P(a|r) or if P(b ∩ r) = 0.*

So, why the book mentioned the **STRICT POSITIVE DISTRIBUTION** as necessary for **INTERSECTION** rule?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\mathbf Y, \mathbf Z$ are independent coinflips (equally likely to be $0$ or $1$), and $\mathbf W = \mathbf Y+ \mathbf Z \bmod 2$. Any two of $\mathbf Y, \mathbf Z,\mathbf W$ determine the third.

Then for absolutely any $\mathbf X$, we have $(\mathbf X \perp \mathbf Y \mid \mathbf Z, \mathbf W)$. That's just because, conditioned on any event of the form $\mathbf Z=z \land \mathbf W=w$, the value of $\mathbf Y$ is constant, and a constant random variable is independent from any other random variable.

Similarly, for absolutely any $\mathbf X$, we have $(\mathbf X \perp \mathbf W \mid \mathbf Z,\mathbf Y)$.

However, if we could conclude that $(\mathbf X \perp \mathbf Y, \mathbf W \mid \mathbf Z)$, then in particular we could conclude that $(\mathbf X \perp \mathbf Y \mid \mathbf Z)$. This is not true in general; in particular, it is false when $\mathbf X = \mathbf Y$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems that the specification of X=Y has ambiguous meanings.
Case 1: if X=Y=CONSTANT, X and Y is independent. 
Then, it trivially has I(X,Y W|Z) and I(X,Y |Z).

Case 2: if X=Y and they are variables like X~N(0,1), X and Y is dependent. 
Then, neither I(X,Y W|Z) nor I(X,Y|Z) is established. 
Hence, in this case, the assertion of ‘I(X,Y W|Z) resulting I(X,Y|Z)’ does not satisfy the prerequisite.

Comment: I have said what the distribution of Y is in this example, so there's no ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

I coincidently read this book on Page6 which, **in some level**, supports my opinion:
**STRICT POSITIVE DISTRIBUTION is not necessary for INTERSECTION rule.**

[image]

Citation: Lauritzen, Steffen L. "Elements of graphical models." Lectures from the XXXVIth International Probability Summer School in St-Flour, France. http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/steffen (2011).